# Issue 'str' object has no attribute 'sign_in_with_email_and_password(email, password)'

Tags: python-3.x, firebase-authentication, pyrebase

I'm trying to logging in with an email and password prompted by the user on terminal.

I tried to use 'pyrebase', 'pyrebase3', and 'pyrebase4' with the following code:

```py
def sign_in():
    global auth
    global user
    email = input("Please, enter your email")
    password = input("Please, enter your password")
    user = auth.sign_in_with_email_and_password(email, password)
    get_user_id(user)
```

However, I keep getting the error:
`AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'sign_in_with_email_and_password'`

It should be straightforward, but I can't think anything else to try!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked for me.

```
def _create_connection(self):
    _firebase = pyrebase.initialize_app(self.config)
    self.auth = _firebase.auth()
    self.user = self.auth.sign_in_with_email_and_password(self.email, self.password)
    self.firebase = _firebase.database()
```

Did you initialize the app and called auth?

Comment: As a matter of fact I accidentally deleted "auth = firebase.auth()". It now works, thank you!